# JQuery Uploadify upload to an URL instead of a script

Tags: jquery, zend-framework, uploadify

I'm using Zend Framework, and doing a little script for uploading files with JQuery plugin Uploadify.
Is it possible to specify an URL for "script" parameter instead of a *.php file ?

```
 $('#file').uploadify({
    'uploader'  : '/js/jquery-plugins/uploadify/2.1.4/uploadify.swf',
    'script'    : 'http://www.mywebsite.com/ajax/upload-file/',
    'folder'    : '/images/logos',
    'fileExt'   : '*.jpeg;*.jpg;*.png;*.gif;*.bmp;*.eps;*.ai;*.pdf;',
    'auto'      : true,
    'onError': function(event, queueID, fileObj, errorObj){
        alert('Erreur, type : ' + errorObj.type + "\n Info : " + errorObj.info);
    }
});
```

I tried this, but no response, no error alert and not any file uploaded. I was wondering if the folder parameter was accepted...
thanks for your help

Comment: I don't understand. What do you mean by "script" exactly?

Comment: Does it also fail using relative path? like `/ajax/upload-file`?

Comment: @Pekka on all examples, the 'script' parameter is : '/js/uploadify/uploadify.php'. It's not flexible for me to use a standalone php file.

Answer (score 0):

You do need to have something listening on the server side for the files, be it a PHP script, a server extension, special software or whatnot.

Or do you really think it would be wise for web servers to allow anyone to upload files anywhere just like that?

Comment: You did not understand my question... Sure, I wrote a script to receive the request, rename and move the uploaded file. But it is in the MVC environment of Zend Framework. I don't have (and don't want to use) a *.php file as uploadify.php, but an url /module/controller/action

Comment: @supertino if the controller is reachable on that URL, that should work

Comment: @supertino7: You should've been more clear in that case. It doesn't matter what's listening on the URL, as long as it can receive file uploads; in fact, the JavaScript has no way of knowing what exactly handles the request. That's how the web works.

Comment: Sorry, maybe my english is a little poor :( It works, I don't know where the problem were....